# c linked list delete function

Tags: c, linked-list

Hello guys I have to write a program in C and I can't make a function deleteByPrice - Function to delete all structures with price more than that I have to type in the console
that's my structure

```
 typedef struct  
    {
       char name[20];
       char id[20];
       float price;
    }Type;

typedef struct Details {
    Type data;
    struct Details *next;
}Node;
```

and that is what i've code but dosen't work:

```
Node *deleteByPrice(Node *start) {
    Node *cur =start;
    Node *next=start;
    float price;
    printf("Insert the price here : ");
    scanf("%f",&price);
    while(cur){
      if (price < cur->data.price){
            next=cur->next;
            free(cur);
            cur = next;
            start=cur;
            } 
       else {           
            next = cur->next->next;
            free(cur->next);
            cur->next = next;
            }
       }
   return cur;
 }
```

Comment: What is not working? Did you compile your code with all warnings and debugging enabled (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux)? Did you use your debugger (i.e. `gdb` on Linux)? What is hapenning?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Thank's a lot for the answers.Your comments were very useful for me.
And again thanks

Answer (score 4):

Well, both branches in your `while` loop are incorrect. First, when the price is less than the price you have been given on the console, you should simply jump to the next element with `cur = cur->next`; no need to mess around with any of the items in the linked list. Second, when the price is greater than the price you have been given and you must delete the item, the deletion has to be done as follows:

1. You have to link the `next` pointer of the *previous* item to the item after the current one (i.e. `cur->next`. Since you are only allowed to move "forward" in your link, this means that you have to keep track of the *previous* item as well as the current one; use an extra pointer called `prev`, which starts from the null pointer and which is set to `cur` before `cur` is stepped to the next item in every iteration of the `while` loop. Once you have `prev`, you can use `prev->next = cur->next` to remove the item to be deleted from the list. (Note that this does not free the item).
2. Once you have removed the item to be deleted from the list, you can free it safely using `free(cur)` and move on to the next item in the list. However, since `cur` is now an invalid pointer after `free`, you must first record `cur->next` in a variable *before* freeing `cur` and then setting `cur` to this recorded value to continue traversing the list.

The whole solution boils down to this:

```
prev = 0; cur = start;
while (cur) {
    if (cur->data.price < price) {
        /* keep the item and move to the next one */
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    } else {
         /* remember the item after the item being removed */
         next = cur->next;
         /* unlink the item from the list */
         if (prev) {
             prev->next = next;
         }
         /* free the unlinked item */
         free(cur);
         /* move to the next item */
         cur = next;
         /* note that prev does not have to be modified here */
     }
 }
```

Also, there is one more catch here. If you happen to remove the first item from the list, this means that the pointer that the function calling `deleteByPrice` was holding to access the first item of the list is not valid anymore, so you *must* update `start` accordingly when you are deleting the first item of the list, and you *must* return `start` at the end of the function so that the caller will know where the "new" head of the list is. I left this out from the above code deliberately -- if you understand my code, then this should not be too hard to add.

Comment: There is one tiny problem about the code, when prev is null and the item is to be removed, `cur = prev->next;` will be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I have overlooked that. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a node, you're *always* modifying `start`, which I assume should point to the list head (the first element). That doesn't seem right.

You should only modify `start` if the element you're modifying is in fact the first one.

Also, it would seem you need to keep track of the previous element in order to change *its* `next`-pointer when you find an element to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node *deleteByPrice(Node *start, float price) {
  Node *cur;
  Node **ptr;

  for (ptr = &start; cur = *ptr; ){
    if (cur->data.price < price){
        ptr = &cur->next;
        continue;
        }
    *ptr = cur->next; 
    free(cur);
   }

   return start;
 }
```